# EAS Android build: succeeds on preview & fails on simulator

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

We are adding an Android build to our existing app so that we can support both devices.

If I use the CI pipeline to build on EAS to install a “preview” app on physical device such as for QA team, with `eas build --platform android --non-interactive --profile development-internal`, it succeeds.
However, if I try a build on EAS to install on the simulator with `eas build --profile development --platform all`, the Android build fails (iOS still successful).

Any ideas why one profile works and the other fails?  The error appears to be linked to `GestureHandlerStateManager`:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProjectDexDebug'.
  A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate

> There was a failure while executing work items
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> **Type devmenu.com.swmansion.common.GestureHandlerStateManager is defined multiple times**: /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/intermediates/mixed_scope_dex_archive/debug/out/1a170d0bd894adab65ecda3a076806fe255d0d45d8e915c332a70cd50745a1ea_0.jar:classes.dex, /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/intermediates/mixed_scope_dex_archive/debug/out/bdd639976e0a4ae11b223df553bc82888ce2938519c96fe038bfb09545b38fb7_0.jar:classes.dex

---

I have tried to figure out the conflict of packages but i can't tell for sure.  Any advice?

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fluidtruck/mobile": "^1.16.6",
    "@fluidtruck/mobile-icons": "^1.16.6",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.6",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@rneui/base": "github:react-native-elements/react-native-elements#base",
    "@rneui/themed": "github:react-native-elements/react-native-elements#themed",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^9.0.0",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.21",
    "expo-analytics-amplitude": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-application": "~4.2.2",
    "expo-asset": "~8.6.3",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-blur": "~11.2.0",
    "expo-clipboard": "~3.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.4",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.3.1",
    "expo-device": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-linking": "~3.2.4",
    "expo-localization": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.2.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.7",
    "geolib": "^3.3.1",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "i18next": "20.2.1",
    "immer": "^9.0.16",
    "json-autotranslate": "1.9.1",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "newrelic-react-native-agent": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.25.3",
    "react-i18next": "^11.15.3",
    "react-native": "0.69.9",
    "react-native-compressor": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.11",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^1.8.8",
    "react-native-error-boundary": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-map-clustering": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.10.2",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-mask-text": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.4",
    "swr": "^1.3.0",
    "use-immer": "^0.7.0"
  },
```

EAS.json:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.4.1",
    "promptToConfigurePushNotifications": false
  },
  "build": {
    "m1": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      }
    },
    "staging": {
      "extends": "m1",
      "node": "16.15.0",
      "yarn": "1.22.5",
      "env": {
        "API_ADDRESS": "ourAPI",
        "LOG_API_ERRORS": "false",
        "ICON": "./src/assets/icon-stage.png",
        "APP_NAME": "Staging LT",
        "BUNDLE_ID": "com.fluidtruck.lt.stage",
        "ENABLE_DEV_FEATURES": "true"
      },
      "ios": {
        "env": {
          "PLATFORM": "ios"
        },
        "image": "default"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "prod": {
      "extends": "m1",
      "node": "16.15.0",
      "yarn": "1.22.5",
      "env": {
        "API_ADDRESS": "ourAPI",
        "LOG_API_ERRORS": "false",
        "ICON": "./src/assets/icon.png",
        "APP_NAME": "LT App",
        "BUNDLE_ID": "com.fluidtruck.lt"
      },
      "ios": {
        "env": {
          "PLATFORM": "ios"
        },
        "image": "default"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle",
        "image": "latest"
      }
    },
    // to release to Test Flight PROD
    "test-flight": {
      "extends": "prod"
    },
    // to release to Test Flight STAGING
    "test-flight:stage": {
      "extends": "staging",
      "env": {
        "LOG_API_ERRORS": "false",
        "APP_NAME": "TF Staging LT"
      }
    },
    // for building test links
    "development-internal": {
      "extends": "staging",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "LOG_API_ERRORS": "true",
        "APP_NAME": "QA Staging LT"
      }
    },
    // for development simulator builds with Native Module packages
    "development": {
      "extends": "staging",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      },
      "env": {
        "LOG_API_ERRORS": "true",
        "APP_NAME": "Dev Sim"
      }
    },
    // for development device builds with Native Module packages
    "development-device": {
      "extends": "staging",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "LOG_API_ERRORS": "true",
        "APP_NAME": "Dev Device"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

app.config:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const bundleIdentifier = process.env.BUNDLE_ID || 'com.fluidtruck.lt.stage';

module.exports = {
  name: process.env.APP_NAME || 'Fluid LT App',
  slug: 'delta',
  owner: 'fluidtruck',
  scheme: 'fluidlt',
  version: '1.6.5', // Only change this if a true version bump is needed.  Apple reviews take longer if you change this field
  orientation: 'portrait',
  userInterfaceStyle: 'automatic',
  icon: process.env.ICON || './src/assets/delta.png',
  privacy: 'unlisted',
  plugins: [
    'newrelic-react-native-agent',
    [
      'react-native-vision-camera',
      {
        cameraPermissionText: 'LT App needs access to your Camera.',
        enableMicrophonePermission: true,
        microphonePermissionText: 'LT App needs access to your Microphone.',
      },
    ],
    'react-native-compressor',
    [
      'expo-image-picker',
      {
        photosPermission: 'This app accesses your photos to let you upload from your library.',
      },
    ],
  ],
  splash: {
    image: './src/assets/splash.png',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  updates: {
    fallbackToCacheTimeout: 0,
  },
  assetBundlePatterns: ['./src/assets/**/*.png', './src/assets/icons/**/*.svg'],
  ios: {
    bundleIdentifier,
    buildNumber: '1.6.11',
    infoPlist: {
      NSCameraUsageDescription: 'This app uses the camera to take pictures & video.',
      NSMicrophoneUsageDescription: 'This app may use your microphone.',
      LSApplicationQueriesSchemes: ['comgooglemaps', 'waze'],
    },
  },
  android: {
    package: bundleIdentifier,
  },
  web: {
    favicon: './src/assets/favicon.png',
  },
  userInterfaceStyle: 'automatic',
  extra: {
    api: process.env.API_ADDRESS,
    bundleIdentifier: bundleIdentifier,
    log_api_errors: process.env.LOG_API_ERRORS,
    newrelic_prod: process.env.NEW_RELIC_PROD,
    newrelic_stage: process.env.NEW_RELIC_STAGE,
    ENABLE_DEV_FEATURES: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.ENABLE_DEV_FEATURES,
    eas: {
      projectId: 'ourID',
    },
  },
```

thank you for helping ID the dependency issue between EAS and why it succeeds on preview build & fails on simulator build.